# Qt Creator places a '->' when I type '.' after a pointer object

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm creating a `QNetworkAccessManager` object in my project the standard way:

```
QNetWorkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager (this)
```

and I am attempting to invoke the `get()` method but whenever I type the `.` after the `manager` object, Qt Creator is inserting a `->` instead, so I end up with

```
manager->
```

when I want

```
manager.
```

Even when I concatenate `manager` and `get()` then move the cursor to the right place, Qt Creator still thinks I'm trying to access a sub-object of manager rather than invoke a method. I've been all over the 'Options' dialogue but I can find any way of disabling this 'feature'. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: i don't see the problem.'->' is what you need.

Comment: And you need ".", because ...?

Comment: QtCreator is simply trying to save you from yourself. Accessing anything from a pointer requires the "->" and not "."

Comment: I don't think your question deserves a -3. I upvoted it as it is well expressed and contains more than enough information to provide an answer to your problem :)

Comment: I have the same problem: I want to invoke get() on a unique_ptr, and in this case "->" is not helping me anyhow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` and `->` don't have anything to do with the difference between "sub-objects" or "methods". Both function members and field members are accessed in the exact same way. `.` is for accessing members of plain objects, and `->` is shorthand for accessing members via pointers. In the usual case, `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`.

Answer (score 3):

You are programming in C#, but Qt requires you to program in C++. If `manager` is declared as a pointer, then `manager.` makes no sense in C++. `Qt` is simply trying to save you from yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else I don't understand why you think you need a '.' rather than '->'. But if this part of QtCreator's auto-completion can be disabled, it should be in **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **Completion**. Then change the **Activate Completion** setting to **Manual**.

In earlier versions, auto-completion could not be disabled at all, but in newer versions you can make some adjustments at least. It works on 2.1.0 but if you have an earlier version it may not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a convenient correction. `manager` is a pointer, so the `->` operator is the correct way to access its members. Nice that Qt Creator has this much built-in intelligence.